# Amperage limit of lead pencil resistor

Tags: resistors, amperage

What is a safe amperage limit for a homemade lead pencil resistor? I made a 25 ohm resistor with a regular wood pencil and would like to know what current it will take without getting hot to the touch. Anyone play with this and know?

Comment: Try it and see? I doubt pencils are characterized this way and there are so many different kinds of pencils that they will surely behave differently.

Comment: Define "hot". *All* current flow in non-superconducting material generates heat.

Comment: It depends if it is a HB, B or 2B pencil.

Comment: Tens to hundreds of miliamps? I did something like this as a kid with a model rail transformer and made a very small carbon arc light.

Comment: Th pencil in this case is type HB 2.

Comment: Is it just the "lead" of the pencil or does it still have the wood around it, because that will most likely catch fire before the graphite melts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2B or not 2B?

The 'lead' is a mix of graphite and clay. The harder pencils will have more clay and will probably be higher resistance. If you've got 25 ohms then 1 A will generate \$P = I^2 \cdot R = 1^2 \cdot 25 = 25 W\$ and on a 15 cm pencil that will be \$\frac {25}{15} = 1.6 W/cm\$. You should notice a rise in temperature.

Beware of any funny effects where the resistivity changes with temperature. I can't think of any but there may be some weird temperature coefficient and if it's negative the current may escalate ...

Report back!

Comment: Don't chew the pencil when current is flowing.

Comment: Temperature coefficient will have a negative region, as you convert the surrounding wood into additional conductive carbon. Above that there will be a positive region as the carbon oxidises into gaseous form.